# Database for available classrooms at the current time

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, database-design

I want to create a database for a mobile app, the app displays to the user (student) all the available (free/dispo) classrooms at the current time.

> For example: a student open the app Monday at 11:00, the app will show
>   classroom 303 as available.

ClassroomLib: 301

```
   |08:00-09:30|09:31-11:10|11:11-12:50|12:51-14:30|14:31-16:10|16:11-17:50|
SAT|  available|           |           |           |available  |available  |
SUN|           |           |           |available  |           |available  |
MON|           |           |available  |           |           |available  |
TUE|           |           |           |available  |           |           |
WED|           |available  |           |           |           |           |
THU|           |           |           |           |available  |available  |
```

ClassroomLib: 303

```
   |08:00-09:30|09:31-11:10|11:11-12:50|12:51-14:30|14:31-16:10|16:11-17:50|
SAT|           |available  |           |           |available  |available  |
SUN|           |           |           |           |           |           |
MON|           |available  |           |           |available  |           |
TUE|           |           |           |           |           |           |
WED|           |           |available  |           |available  |available  |
THU|           |           |           |           |available  |available  |
```

I designed the db as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE classrooms(
classroomId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
classroomLib VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
);
CREATE TABLE schedules(
dayWeek INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
hStart TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
hEnd TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
);
CREATE TABLE dispos(
classroomId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
dayWeek INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
hStart TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
hEnd TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
classroomDispo INTEGER, #boolean
);
```

I got a lot of classrooms, and for each classroom i got 36 entries, is there a better architecture ?

Comment: Do you really need rows for unscheduled time slots?

Comment: No, i don't but i need a way to modify/add a slot.

Answer (score 0):

Split the application.

Use the database to store raw information -- probably just what hours are assigned to what activities.

Use the application to derive what is 'available' and to pretty-print the output.

This split will make "live simpler".